# Choosing the right word between front/ahead/forward

Tags: word-usage, difference

Consider these expressions:

> The place is smelling very bad, the smell seems to be **coming from the front/ahead**
>
> When I got off the car, I saw a very fast car coming towards me **from the front/ahead**.
>
> Can you please come **forward/ahead**  a bit,I won't have to talk so loud.

I am always confused about the difference between these three words: **front/ahead/forward**. Can anyone help me understand these expressions?

Answer (score 4):

Ordinarily, *ahead* means *further away, in the direction the speaker (or addressee) **is travelling***. But no-one appears to actually be moving in OP's examples, so we have to consider other possibilities.

*Forward* means *in the direction the speaker (or addressee) **is facing***.

*The front* means either *the side of some object **nearest to the speaker***, or *the side from which people **usually approach/see*** the object.

In fact, *ahead* would do for #1, but only if "the place" refers to an area you're travelling through at the time. If "the place" in #1 is, for example, a house, *the front* (or *the back, the side*) would be fine.

For #2, *ahead* could refer to the direction you were travelling before you got **out of** (not **off**) the car. *The front* doesn't make a lot of sense, because there's nothing to suggest *the front of **what** [object]*.

I can't see how to contrive a context where *ahead* makes sense for #3. *Come/move **forward*** seems most likely here.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer,By "area traveling through the time" you mean something like a vechile?

Comment: @Thor: It would be just as natural to speak of something happening (or being located) *[up] ahead* if you were *walking*. There normally has to be actual *movement* involved when you use the word "ahead". It might be that you've temporarily stopped moving (or maybe haven't even started yet), but the *direction* of past/present/potential/future movement has to be obvious.

Answer (score 3):

For #2, you could say

> When I got **out of** the car, I saw a very fast car **ahead**, coming towards me.

"Ahead" locates the very fast car (its location in front of you). "coming towards me" is a separate fact and not related to the location.

For #3, "forward" is correct, but you could also say

> Can you please **move toward me** a bit, **so** I won't have to talk so loud.

For this situation it seems more natural to say it this way. "so" is necessary in both to connect the phrases.

For #1, "front" is correct, as it states a location in the place.

So in general:
**Front** is a location not relative to the speaker or subject (unless otherwise specified, such as "in front of me").
**Ahead** is a location in front of the speaker or subject.
**Forward** is a direction of movement.